# How I can use swap 32 bits in Verilog? example: (Bit 0 is copied to position 31 Bit 31 is copied to position 0)

Tags: verilog, modelsim

How I can use swap 32 bits in Verilog? example: (Bit 0 is copied to position 31 Bit 31 is copied to position 0)
p[0] <= p[31];
p[31] <= p[0];

Comment: p[0] <= p[31]; p[31] <= p[0]; I want more simple way to swap 32bit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest to use `generate` construct:

```verilog
wire [31 : 0] swapped;
genvar i;

generate
    for(i = 0; i < 32; i = i + 1) begin
            assign swapped[i] = p[31 - i];
    end
endgenerate
```